# Си: вывести номер дня недели по его названию

Tags: c, вывод, сравнение

В единственной строке файла записано три буквы, обозначающие день недели на английском языке. Требуется вывести номер этого дня недели.
В файле нет пробелов. Первая буква заглавная, остальные две маленькие. Гарантируется,
что с трёх записанных букв начинается название дня недели на английском языке.
Вот мой собственный код, программа ничего не выводит. Что бы вы посоветовали сделать/исправить?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c, d, e;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &c, &d, &e);
    
    if((c=='M')&&(d=='o')&&(e=='n'))
                printf("1");
              
    if((c=='T')&&(d=='u')&&(e=='e'))
                printf("2");
               
    if((c=='W')&&(d=='e')&&(e=='d'))
                printf("3");
               
    if((c=='T')&&(d=='h')&&(e=='u'))
                printf("4");
               
    if((c=='F')&&(d=='r')&&(e=='i'))
                printf("5");
               
    if((c=='S')&&(d=='a')&&(e=='t'))
                printf("6");
               
    if((c=='S')&&(d=='u')&&(e=='n'))
                printf("7");
}
```

Comment: Заменить `"%d %d %d"` на `"%c %c %c"`.

Comment: А а файле что написано? `S u n`, так? Или `Sun`?

Comment: Так же проверьте возвращаемое значение, если оно не равно 3м, то у вас не считались данные.

Comment: @ヒミコ "в файле нет пробелов".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку задача, вообще-то, связана с анализом *строк символов*, то и решать ее наиболее логично, используя средства работы со строками, которые для Си в основном находятся в заголовочном файле `string.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[10];

  if (!fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) // прочтем строку файла
    return (perror("get line"), 1);
  str[3] = 0; // ограничимся первыми 3-мя символами
  
  const char *days = "MonTueWedThuFriSatSun";
  const char *p = strstr(days, str);   // найдем вхождение прочитанного дня в перечне всех дней недели
  int  n = p - days;   // перейдем от адресов к индексу символов в строке

  if (p && n % 3 == 0) // проверим, введенные данные это в самом деле первые 3 буквы дня?
    printf("%d\n", n / 3 + 1);
  else
    printf("`%s` is not a day\n", str);
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! :)

Comment: @A_Hatake если ответ решил вопрос, поставьте галку слева от него

Answer (score 4):

Ну раз уж

> Гарантируется, что с трёх записанных букв начинается название дня недели на английском языке

грех этим не попользоваться...

```
int day()
{
    char nm[10];
    scanf("%s",nm);
    long long x = nm[0]+nm[1]+nm[2]-300;
    return (((((101047ll*x+694384ll)*x-19207693ll)*x-61935874ll)*x
             +1060034136ll)*x-1218412800)*(2+x)/2058376320+1;

}
```

Убедитесь, что [работает](https://ideone.com/YpRJxo)...

:)

Comment: Не хватает замера производительности, чтобы убедиться, что ваш способ быстрее чем множество if'ов (или медленнее ;) )

Comment: @wololo Хотите по гамбургскому счету? Извольте: https://ideone.com/NXnXzU

Comment: Можно использовать значение `nm[0]+nm[1]+nm[2] - 288` в качестве индекса массива. Это существенно ускорит процесс. [Пример](https://ideone.com/vfeV6O) ;)

Comment: а как магию подбирал, если не секрет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да обычный интерполяционный многочлен. Недолго думая, загнал в Wolfram :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так: (как отметил [wololo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262953/wololo) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183007/%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E#comment-2058916), нужно просто поменять формат принимаемых данных) ну и от себя добавил проверку.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   char c, d, e;
   scanf("%c %c %c", &c, &d, &e); 
   if((c=='M')&&(d=='o')&&(e=='n'))
       printf("1\n");
   else if((c=='T')&&(d=='u')&&(e=='e'))
       printf("2\n");
   else if((c=='W')&&(d=='e')&&(e=='d'))
       printf("3\n");
   else if((c=='T')&&(d=='h')&&(e=='u'))
       printf("4\n");
   else if((c=='F')&&(d=='r')&&(e=='i'))
       printf("5\n");
   else if((c=='S')&&(d=='a')&&(e=='t'))
       printf("6\n");          
   else if((c=='S')&&(d=='u')&&(e=='n'))
       printf("7\n");
   else 
       printf("day not found\n");
}
```

И ещё момент, на западе в основном воскресенье это не 7й день недели, а первый)

Comment: не «на западе», а в Америке и Азии... а по ISO'шному стандарту первый — понедельник...

Comment: Как будто это сильно изменило смысл)) Вы прекрасно поняли что имелось ввиду и все кто будут читать тоже это поймут. Не стоит придираться к словам)) Так как это русскоязычный сайт и основная часть русскоязычных пользователей привыкла слышать с экранов телевизоров и роликов ютуба (абстрактное название "запад", вместо конкретных стран или материков/островов). Насчет ISO-стандарта, спасибо что уточнили.

Comment: нум... во-первых, «запад» — ложная общность, ИМХО пора перестать употреблять этот исторический штамп... , а, во-вторых, распространённость практики сильно не совпадает с тем, что обычно называется «запад»... в общем и не «в основном» и не «на западе»: пройти молча не получилось... короче говоря, не обращай внимания... хобби у меня такое — подмечать нудные культурологические неточности =)